# Do wound and multiple-action penalties apply to damage rolls?

Tags: d6-system, mini-six

In Mini Six, the rules for multiple actions are brief:

> Characters may attempt to do more than one thing on a turn 
> by withholding one die from every action they attempt for each 
> action beyond the first. For instance, if a character tries to shoot 
> twice, he will subtract one die from each attempt.

Similarly, the rules for impairment as a result of being wounded are only printed in the wound table:

```
Stunned: -1D for all remaining actions this round and next round.
Wounded: -1D to all actions until healed.
...
```

I don't know if damage rolls are affected by this penalty, but I can see fluff arguments both ways. If you're using a melee weapon, you're not going to hit as hard when you're about to pull the weapon and go for another attack. However, if you're shooting somebody with a gun, it makes sense for it to do full damage, unless damage rolls are factoring in *how well* you hit as well as how powerful the weapon is.

My question is this: under RAW, do these penalties apply to damage rolls as well as to-hit rolls, or not? If there's no definite answer in the Mini Six PDF, I'm happy to accept an answer citing another D6 System game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, with the wording you've quoted. Partially, in my experience with past D6 games.**

In my group's interpretation of the rules (D6 *Star Wars*, in our case), damage and soak weren't actions. Rather, they were the outcome of actions. This is based on the Rolling Actions description in the system:

> Characters roll their skill dice (or their attribute dice if they haven't improved the skill) whenever they do something important and there's a risk of failure.

This made it sufficiently clear to us that an "action" was a skill check that we never really questioned it. You may want to check the definition of an action in *Mini Six* to make sure they haven't changed it.

As soak and damage aren't actions, they aren't affected by the multiple action penalty.

Wounds were a slightly different matter. Wounds were worded differently in D6 *Star Wars*:

> *Stunned* characters suffer a penalty of -1D to skill and attribute rolls for the rest of the round and for the next round.

Our interpretation of this at the time was that the character would take a penalty to damage based on Strength (e.g. from a knife), but that static damage (e.g. from a gun) would be unaffected.

However, we didn't penalize soak. My memory is that there was a rule that specifically told us this, but I don't see it in any obvious places now. So unless I've simply missed it, we may have been playing it inconsistently all along!

*Answer based on D6 Star Wars, Revised and Expanded*

Comment: Being heavily abbreviated, Mini Six doesn't really define "action". I can see how the stunned condition would reduce melee weapon damage but multiple actions wouldn't. As for defences like dodge, parry, block and soak, Mini Six makes them static numbers (so soak is always might dice * 3 + pips + armour and so on). Under that system, I wouldn't adjust soak for a stunned or wounded character. So while it might be inconsistent under D6 Star Wars, it appears to be the correct approach under Mini Six. Thanks for a thorough answer.

Comment: D6 SW indeed notes that the only modifier for soak is armor.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [D6 "REUP"](http://www.starwarstimeline.net/WestEndGames/The%20Roleplaying%20Game%20Revised%20Expanded%20Updated%20WRP.pdf) version clarifies (emphasis mine):

> For each action taken beyond the first, the player must subtract 1D
>   from all skill or attribute rolls (***but not*** damage, damage resistance,
>   or initiative rolls). Thus, trying to do four actions in one round
>   gives the character a −3D modifier to each roll